# How to make amd work?

Tags: drivers, steam, amd-graphics

I'm trying to play fallout 4 on Steam proton. But it have very low FPS (19-23)... When O had Windows OS it runs much more faster with better graphic settings.

I have:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Intel Core i7 6820HQ
- AMD Radeon HD 8750M
- 16GB RAM

So, I thought, that fallout 4 used integrated (intel) videocard. And it seems like it is.

I use [corectrl](https://gitlab.com/corectrl/corectrl) program to watch when my amd-videocard working and when it rest.

I started steam with `DRI_PRIME=1 steam`, and on this screenshot:

[image: this screenshot] you can see how AMD is working (right part of picture).

But when I running fallout 4, this diagram looks like 4 direct lines without any changes...

Also I tried to turn of the AMD videocard and guess what? I had the VERY same result 19-23 fps...

Here is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i -EA3 "3d|display|vga"`:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 [8086:191b] (rev 06)
> DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
> Subsystem: Dell HD Graphics 530 [1028:06df]
> Kernel driver in use: i915
> --
> 00:16.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family KT Redirection [8086:a13d] (rev 31)
> Subsystem: Dell 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family KT Redirection [1028:06df]
> Kernel driver in use: serial
> 00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] [8086:a102] (rev 31)
> --
> 01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] [1002:6600] (rev 81)
> Subsystem: Dell Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] [1028:06df]
> Kernel driver in use: radeon
> Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu

So the question is: **How to make Fallout 4 use AMD videocard?**

Comment: I think i found the answer... almost.

I found file, which have next line:
sD3DDevice="Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)"
So one website recommends to change this string to my amd videocard, but how to get valid name?

Comment: I believe all you need is to run `sudo lshw -C video | grep product`

Comment: @Terrance I tried to paste output from your command, but it didn't help.
The output looks like
`product: Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M]
product: **HD Graphics 530**`
And the default setting of `sD3DDevice` is `Intel(R) **HD Graphics 530** (SKL GT2)`
Do you see the coincidence? Maybe you have some idea where can I get the first and last part of full name?

Comment: You would just add `Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M` as that is the name of the AMD card.

Comment: @Terrance Unfortunately, it's not helped(
Maybe you have any else suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have 2 video cards in my system so I cannot duplicate what you have.  Sorry.

Comment: @Terrance, That's ok, Thank you for help!

Comment: Giving you an upvote to help you on your way. Maybe someone here has experienced the same thing and possibly will know.